# My localhost works but the heroku database doesn't

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I'm using the remote database URL on my laptop and it works perfectly on localhost. When I upload to heroku, it won't save new users to the database. It's still connecting to the database to start the web application (I think). I see the 'session' storage increasing by one every time I visit the website online. And I can definitely create new users and do everything it's supposed to on my laptop.

I've tried changing versions of the database from mongodb 2.6 to 3.0. I've tried switching out versions of mongoose so that they're compatible with the version of mongodb (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html).

I've tried deleting node_modules and doing a fresh npm install.

Been debugging this for months and have probably put over 100 hours in to it with no solution. Can someone please help? I have no idea why the database would work on this machine but not the heroku server. All I've figured out so far is that the reason it's not working is the database won't create documents from heroku.

Comment: This sounds like it's likely a very app-specific issue. My guess would be the app isn't really connecting to the same database. Do you see any errors with `heroku logs --tail` when you try to do db ops? Have you put in detailed logging at every step of the database connection and write process? I'd recommend opening a ticket. Mention my name and support will escalate to me.